# I need a Handbrake preset for a Samsung GT-i5500 Europa please?

Tags: video, samsung-europa

I need a Handbrake preset for a Samsung GT-i5500 Europa please?
This is to convert video clips and movies etc into a format that can be viewed on my phone.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view Android's supported Media formats here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I would recommend H.264 video and AACv2 audio, for the best quality.  The dimensions depend on the dimensions of your phone -- in your case, 320x240.  It's not the most powerful phone so you may want to experiment with the quality to get it playable but also looking good.

Comment: Additionally the container for the video should be 3gp which Handbrake does not handle. I am going to do the conversion in "Super" instead. These settings worked however once I had converted the mp4 output of Handbrake to 3gp

Comment: Hmm, OK.  The developer guide says mp4 should have been OK.

Comment: It's possible that different settings may have worked within an mp4 container. I used low quality settings within mp4. It wouldn't play. Same settings with 3GP container, worked fine.

Comment: I finally found a setting in Handbrake that works fine for mp4 files as follows: Container=mp4 file Picture size width=320 height=240 Video Codec=mpeg-4 (ff mpeg). Framerate=12 2 pass encoding=checked. Avg bitrate=56 Audio source=automatic codec=aac (faac) mixdown=mono sample rate=44.1 bitrate=32